# Inserting code from seperate source file (ASP.NET/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, include

How can I insert code into a page in ASP.Net from a seperate source file?

Say I have:

```
   <% 
         Response.Write("hello world");
   %>
```

How can I make it something like:

```
   <% include(helloworld.cs) %>
```

I know how it work sin the header with the <%@ and CodeFile= but I can't make it work for different spots of code. Is there a way ASP.Net handles this? I've tried googling but not sure what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option not mentioned yet is to use [ASP.NET Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx). This is useful to have a consistent look and feel (and code behind) in the master page which extends to the child pages.

Answer (score 1):

You <strike>can't</strike> shouldn't.

Instead, you should create a [User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx).

Comment: This is not correct. You can use old-style server-side includes. I agree that you *shouldn't* do it, and should use User Controls instead, though.

Comment: Absolutely yes, SLaks; with Server-side code in them. The content of the included file runs exactly as if you had typed it in the source file that references it.

Comment: @Andrew: What are you talking about?  Can you provide a link?

Comment: I've just done it myself with a file named "inc.inc" and included it in an ASP.NET 4.0 page. the inc.inc file used a server-side tag like so: `<%= DateTime.Now%>` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Andrew: [I take that back](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3207d0e3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  I never knew that; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a class library and add a reference to the library.

link that may help:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306575

Comment: I too think a Object Oriented approach would be appropriate :)

Comment: Creating a class library just to include some boilerplate UI markup seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can use old-style Server-Side include tags like so:

```
<!-- #include virtual="/inc.inc" -->
```

But I do **not** recommend it. You should use [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) instead; they give you more capability, and do not potentially expose server-side code if someone should happen to try to request them directly.

If you nevertheless decide to use includes like that, note that the content of the file is included in the ASPX/ASCX source code just as if you had typed it right in the main source file itself.